# Loop to change block position

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Matlab script that creates a Model Block for each element i found in  a text file.

The problem is that all Models are created on each other in the window. So i'm trying to make a loop like:

```
for each element in text file
    I add a Model block 
    I place right to the previous one
end
```

So it can look like this: 
[image]

As you can see on the left, all models are on each other and I would like to place them like the one on the right.

I tried this:

```
m = mdlrefCountBlocks(diagrammeName)+500;
add_block('simulink/Ports & Subsystems/Model',[diagrammeName '/' component_NameValue]);
set_param(sprintf('%s/%s',diagrammeName,component_NameValue), 'ModelFile',component_NameValue); 
size_blk = get_param(sprintf('%s/%s',diagrammeName,component_NameValue),'Position'); 
X = size_blk(1,1); 
Y = size_blk(1,2); 
Width = size_blk(1,3); 
Height = size_blk(1,4); 
set_param(sprintf('%s/%s',diagrammeName,component_NameValue),'Position',[X+m Y X+Width Y+Height]);
```

Inside the loop but it returns an error `Invalid definition of rectangle. Width and height should be positive.`

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position property of a block does actually not contain its width and height, but the positions of the corners on the canvas (see [Common Block Properties](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/common-block-parameters.html)):

> vector of coordinates, in pixels: `[left top right bottom]`
>
> The origin is the upper-left corner of the Simulink Editor canvas before any canvas resizing. Supported coordinates are between -1073740824 and 1073740823, inclusive. Positive values are to the right of and down from the origin. Negative values are to the left of and up from the origin.

So change your code to e.g.:

```
size_blk = get_param(sprintf('%s/%s',diagrammeName,component_NameValue),'Position'); 
set_param(sprintf('%s/%s',diagrammeName,component_NameValue),'Position', size_blk + [m 0 0 0]);
```